# Creating a custom dropdown using overlays in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, overlay

I am trying to create a dropdown menu in Flutter without using the built-in components or any public packages. I want to use a TextField to detect clicks and create an overlay to show the Lists of actual objects. However, I am facing a challenge. I was trying to utilize the Focus changes to know when the user clicks away from the text field and the overlay. As the overlay is a separate component from the TextField, every click on the overlay registers a focus change too. How can I get around this problem and close the overlay only when the user clicks outside both widgets not just the text field itself.

Comment: check how `RawAutocomplete` is doing this, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/90c64ed42ba53a52d18f0cb3b17666c8662ed2a0/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/autocomplete.dart#L122